# post command does not return elements from safari

Tags: html, post, safari

I have written a small web server in micro framework 4.2 that listens on port 81. It sends HTML web pages with a form and waits for the POST to come back with the elements from the browser. It works fine with every browser I have tested it with except Apple's Safari brower. At the end of the web page I have two cariage returns line feed pairs. Any ideas why the POS elements are not returned? Below is the first few lines from a web page I am sending.

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Settings</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="POST" action="Times.htm">

   <h1>Set Zone Times</h1>
   <p>Zone 1 maximum time <select size="1" name="Zone1MaxTime">
   <option>5</option>
   <option>10</option>
```